# Передача типов QObject из Python в QML

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qml, pyqt

Хочу передать тип Interface из типа атрибута(свойство или функция тоже пойдет) класса Service в QML. Вот таким образом не получается:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import Service 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.11
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 240
    Service {
        id: service
    }
    ColumnLayout {
    Text {
        text: service.Text
    }
    Repeater {
        model: service.Interfaces
        delegate: Rectangle {
            color: "#b0dfb0"

            height: 80
            // как встроить сюда тип Interface? 
            Text {
                text: "bar"
            }
            Text {
                text: modelData.Text
            }
            Repeater {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
    }
}


import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtProperty, QCoreApplication, QObject, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtQml import qmlRegisterType, QQmlComponent, QQmlEngine
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


class Controller(QObject):
    @pyqtProperty(str)
    def Text(self):
        return "hello word"+repr(self)


class Interface(QObject):
    @pyqtProperty(str)
    def Text(self):
        return "bar"+repr(self)

    @pyqtProperty(list)
    def Controllers(self):
        return [Controller() for c in range(2)]

class Service(QObject):
    @pyqtProperty(str)
    def Text(self):
        return "foo"+repr(self)

    @pyqtProperty(list)
    def Interfaces(self):
        return [Interface() for i in range(2)]




if __name__ == '__main__':
    qmlRegisterType(Service, 'Service', 1, 0, 'Service')
    qmlRegisterType(Interface, 'Service', 1, 0, 'Interface')
    qmlRegisterType(Controller, 'Service', 1, 0, 'Controller')

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load("view.qml")
    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Можно как-то передать аргументы конструктора в QML и инициализировать тип тут на месте?

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть больше кода )

Comment: так дальше код уже не работает

Comment: А что за класс такой Service и о каких интерфесах речь?

Comment: это простые классы с пропертями и методами. Сервис - следит за конфигурацией, в конфигурации появляется устройство, этому устройству надо вывести гуи. у устройства может быть несколько свойств со списками. Третий класс можно словарем с текстовыми полями отдать, но хотелось бы проперти с сигналами.

Comment: Устройство может подключаться/отключаться в процессе, то есть с течением времени? У класса Service есть сигнал об изменении количества подключенных устройств?

Comment: сигнал есть, отключаться-подключаться будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тип Repeater отвечает за создание некоторого количества одинаковых объектов. В вашем случае, насколько я понимаю, это GUI подключенных устройств чьи свойства доступны через интерфейсы, получаемых из класса Service.

Возможный вариант реализации (ваш случай):

```
ApplicationWindow {

    Service
    {
        id: service
        // Изменилось количество устройств
        on<Сигнал_изменения_количества_устройств>: {
            rep.model = /*получить текущее количество устройств*/
        }
    }

    //...
    Repeater
    {
        id: rep
        Rectangle { // В делегате доступна переменная index
            Text {
                text: "Имя устройства: " + service.Interfaces[index].name
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Класс Service (С++):

```
public Service : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE const DeviceInterface& device(int index);
signals:
    void deviceCountChanged(int count);
}
```

Класс Service (PyQt) (пример [тут](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/qml.html)) + с учетом вашего ответа:

```
class Service(QObject):
    @pyqtProperty(QQmlListProperty)
    def Interfaces(self):
        return QQmlListProperty(Interface, self, self._devices)
```

класс DeviceInterface должен быть зарегистрирован в qml

Comment: device это слот? слот также не отдает объект

Comment: @eri нет это не слот. Сейчас подправлю

Comment: попробую перевести на pyqt... но там вроде какието недоделки с invokable

Comment: @eri подправил для пикута

Comment: я так пробовал. тип не регистрируется на pyqtProperty

Comment: @eri кавычки не нужны. Мой косяк

Comment: Пробовал запустить? и с кавычками и без кавычек вчера у меня такой проперти отдавался как null

Comment: Правда теперь интересно как отдать один объект...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91970/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-eri).

Answer (score 2):

Победил задачу через `QQmlListProperty` инициализировав её как [только чтение](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fvza.png)

python

```
class Interface(QObject):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,*a,**kw):
        super().__init__(parent,*a,**kw)

    @pyqtProperty(str)
    def Text(self):
        return "bar"+repr(self)


class Service(QObject):
    @pyqtProperty(str)
    def Text(self):
        return "foo"+repr(self)


    m_interfaces = []
    cha = pyqtSignal()

    @pyqtProperty(QQmlListProperty, notify=cha)
    def Interfaces(self):
        def count(p):
            print(p)
            return  len(p.m_interfaces)
        def at(p,i):
            print([p,i])
            print(p.m_interfaces[i])
            return p.m_interfaces[i]

        return QQmlListProperty(Interface, self, count=count, at=at)


    @pyqtSlot()
    def AppendInterface(self):
        self.m_interfaces.append(Interface(self))
        print(self.m_interfaces)
        self.cha.emit()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    qmlRegisterType(Service, 'Service', 1, 0, 'Service')
    qmlRegisterType(Interface, 'Service', 1, 0, 'Interface')
    qmlRegisterType(Controller, 'Service', 1, 0, 'Controller')

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load("view.qml")
    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

qml

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import Service 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.11
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 240
    Service {
        id: service
        Component.onCompleted: {
            this.AppendInterface()
            this.AppendInterface()
        }
    }
    ColumnLayout {
    Text {
        text: service.Text
    }
    Repeater {
        model: service.Interfaces
        delegate: Rectangle {
            color: "#b0dfb0"

            height: 80
            // как встроить сюда тип Interface?

            ColumnLayout {
            Text {
                text: "bar" + index
            }
            Text {
                text: modelData.Text
            }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Один объект можно получить через слот или проперти

```
@pyqtProperty(QObject)
def oneInterface(self):
    return Interface(self)

@pyqtSlot(int,result=QObject)
def oneInterfaceSlot(self,i):
    return self.m_interfaces[i]
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А целом как оно?

Comment: Вцелом в каком смысле?

Comment: Работает как ожидается? Мне же тоже интересно для себя, мало ли

Comment: Да, объект покорно лежит в modelData, а на экране два разных интерфейса